# SAPUI5 How to display only the first value of an entitySet

Tags: data-binding, odata, sapui5

I'm currently working on an app for displaying some data, which I get from an *EntitySet*.

The mockup for my application looks like this:

[image]

On the top, I have an input Field with a button to apply the filter with the value of the input.
After that, there are 5 `ObjectListItems` at the moment. I don't know if its the right thing to use.
Under these boxes, there is a table to display further information about the chosen entry. The table works as intended and looks good.

My Problem now lies within these 5 Boxes.

`{Binding1}` to `{Binding5}` contains always the same Value for one giving "Input Value". Which means, `{Binding1}` for example would be 7 times `Value1` and `{Binding2}` 7 times `Value2`. Now i want these to be shown only one time in there own Box.

Values, which are differ per row, are shown in the table below.

I don't know how I could make this work...

**View**:

```
            <l:VerticalLayout width="100%">
                <l:BlockLayout background="Dashboard">
                    <l:BlockLayoutRow>
                        <l:BlockLayoutCell width="100%">
                            <Title text="Test {Binding1} - {Binding2}"/>
                        </l:BlockLayoutCell>
                    </l:BlockLayoutRow>
                    <l:BlockLayoutRow>
                        <l:BlockLayoutCell width="50%">
                            <ObjectListItem
                                intro="Site"
                                icon="sap-icon://building"
                                title="{Binding3}"
                                />
                        </l:BlockLayoutCell>
                        <l:BlockLayoutCell width="50%">
                            <ObjectListItem
                                intro="Adress"
                                icon="sap-icon://addresses"
                                title="{Binding4}"
                                />
                        </l:BlockLayoutCell>
                    </l:BlockLayoutRow>
                    <l:BlockLayoutRow>
                        <l:BlockLayoutCell width="50%">
                            <ObjectListItem
                                intro="Supplier"
                                icon="sap-icon://supplier"
                                title="{Binding5}"
                                />
                        </l:BlockLayoutCell>
                        <l:BlockLayoutCell width="50%">
                            <ObjectListItem
                                intro="Currency"
                                icon="sap-icon://lead"
                                title="{Binding6}"
                                />
                        </l:BlockLayoutCell>
                    </l:BlockLayoutRow> 
                </l:BlockLayout>
            </l:VerticalLayout>

            <Table
                id="table1"
                items="{path: '/EntitySet'}">
                <columns>
                    <Column>
                        <Text text="Category"/> 
                    </Column>
                    ...             
                </columns>
                <items>
                    <ColumnListItem>
                        <cells>

                            <Text text="{Category}"/>
                            ...
                        </cells>
                    </ColumnListItem>
                </items>
            </Table>
```

**Controller**:

```
return Controller.extend("com.zf.cmi.zz1ui5_ivdp.controller.View", {            
     onInit: function() {               

        },
        onPress: function() {                       
            var oTable = this.getView().byId("table1");                 
            var oTableBinding = oTable.getBinding("items");
            var filter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("InvoiceNo", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, this.byId("search").getValue());
            oTableBinding.filter(filter);                   
        } 
    });
```

Is there a way to show the value of `{Binding1}` - `{Binding5}` only one time at their given Box?

*edit

As an addition, the result of my XML model would look like this:

```
Entry1:                    Entry2:                   Entry3:
Binding1 = a               Binding1 = a              Binding1 = a 
Binding2 = b               Binding2 = b              Binding2 = b
Binding3 = ...             Binding3 = ...            Binding3 = ...
Binding10 = 1 (Table)      Binding10 = 2             Binding10 = 3
```

Comment: Why do you get the model from the owner component and then set it to the core?

Comment: @Marc oh sorry, it's just from an earlier try, forgot to delete it

Answer (score 1):

If It's a JSON Model you can use binding path like this `{/Binding1/0}`.

If It's a XML Model you need to know the KEY to set the binding path like this `{/Binding1('Key')}`. If you don't know the key, you have to use JS in controller to get it or change/create your service to return the data in an away better to you UI5 show it.

### Using JS Controller

```
onInit: function () {
    this.getView().bindElement({
        path: "/BINDING_PATH",
        events: {
            dataReceived: function (oEvent) {
                var data = oEvent.getParameter('data');
                var array_paths = oEvent.getSource().getModel();
            }.bind(this),
        }
    });
}
```

Now on `data` you have all data returned by service, and on `array_path` you have an array with path and data, you can get the array KEY (that's the service path) to binding to your controls.

Comment: First, thanks for your advice, it's an XML model, but the KEY which is required differ any time there is an other input...

And I can't change the service either...
Could you help me with the JS in the controller?

Comment: Hi, I updated the answer with a little sample of how to do using JS in the controller

Comment: Thank you,  I may do something wrong but "data" stays undefined. I'm right that my /BINDING_PATH is the same as the one in "items={path: "/EntitySet"}?

Comment: yeah I used this, but my "var data = oEvent.getParameter('Binding1');" gives data = undefined

Comment: I think you have to study JS a little bit more, your errors are so basic. Try use  `oEvent.getParameter('data');`

Comment: I know i have to study JS a lot more, but I try to improve and I'm grateful for any advice I get. I tried 'data' at first but the result is the same, still data = undefined

Comment: first you have to see if your service is returning any data, see the network tab in devtools of your browser, also you can inspect the variable oEvent to se what you got.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177807/discussion-between-penrock-and-i-b-n).

Answer (score 0):

```
<ObjectListItem
    intro="Site"
    icon="sap-icon://building"
    title="{/EntrySet('1')/Binding3}" />
```

is the same as

```
<ObjectListItem
    binding="{/EntrySet('1')}"
    intro="Site"
    icon="sap-icon://building"
    title="{Binding3}" />
```

is the same as

```
<ObjectListItem
    id="Item3"
    intro="Site"
    icon="sap-icon://building"
    title="{Binding3}" />


const iID = 1;
const sKey = "/EntrySet('" + iID + "')"; 
this.byId("Item3").bindElement(sKey);
```

You can then replace `iID` with something meaningful depending on the input.

Comment: Well... this could be a solution, but in my case, I don't know the "iID" when the input is set, or more so, lets say I use "a" for input, my model gives me 8 Entries with varies "iID", so I don't know any of these 8 "iID" to begin with. 

Isn't there a simple way to just say "Only show the first entry". 

Or maybe some other ways than a list?

Comment: I don't know your flow. Is it `Enter into Input > Press Filter > Use first result of filtered List to show in the 5 boxes`?

Comment: Yes, thats the flow, at the moment I got 8 results per box

Comment: OK. **A)** After pressing filter you'll receive data (`oTableBinding.attachChange(function(oEvent) {})`. Read the key of the first item. **B)** You can implement an OData function import that does the filtering and returns exactly one item. Store this item in a local JSONModel and show it in the boxes.

Comment: I will try my best with option A, thank you so far for helping

Comment: Well I don't seem to get it right... I used the attachChange in my onPress(), but it seems I don't read the key in the right way...